# Adding a toggled button/icon to App in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Looking for a way to implement a button that can be toggled back and forth between favorites and history. Is there a way to do this in flutter.

[image]

Comment: You can lookout for switch widget

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://felixblaschke.medium.com/custom-animated-control-elements-with-flutter-8c0d352d7136), you could probably tone it to your liking and create what you are looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using a custom widget like this one below:

toggle_button.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ToggleButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;

  final String leftDescription;
  final String rightDescription;

  final Color toggleColor;
  final Color toggleBackgroundColor;
  final Color toggleBorderColor;

  final Color inactiveTextColor;
  final Color activeTextColor;

  final double _leftToggleAlign = -1;
  final double _rightToggleAlign = 1;

  final VoidCallback onLeftToggleActive;
  final VoidCallback onRightToggleActive;

  const ToggleButton(
      {Key? key,
      required this.width,
      required this.height,
      required this.toggleBackgroundColor,
      required this.toggleBorderColor,
      required this.toggleColor,
      required this.activeTextColor,
      required this.inactiveTextColor,
      required this.leftDescription,
      required this.rightDescription,
      required this.onLeftToggleActive,
      required this.onRightToggleActive})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ToggleButtonState createState() => _ToggleButtonState();
}

class _ToggleButtonState extends State<ToggleButton> {
  double _toggleXAlign = -1;

  late Color _leftDescriptionColor;
  late Color _rightDescriptionColor;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _leftDescriptionColor = widget.activeTextColor;
    _rightDescriptionColor = widget.inactiveTextColor;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: widget.width,
      height: widget.height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: widget.toggleBackgroundColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(50.0),
        ),
        border: Border.all(color: widget.toggleBorderColor),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          AnimatedAlign(
            alignment: Alignment(_toggleXAlign, 0),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            child: Container(
              width: widget.width * 0.5,
              height: widget.height,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: widget.toggleColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(50.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(
                () {
                  _toggleXAlign = widget._rightToggleAlign;

                  _leftDescriptionColor = widget.inactiveTextColor;
                  _rightDescriptionColor = widget.activeTextColor;
                },
              );

              widget.onRightToggleActive();
            },
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment(-1, 0),
              child: Container(
                width: widget.width * 0.5,
                color: Colors.transparent,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  widget.leftDescription,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: _leftDescriptionColor,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(
                () {
                  _toggleXAlign = widget._leftToggleAlign;

                  _leftDescriptionColor = widget.activeTextColor;
                  _rightDescriptionColor = widget.inactiveTextColor;
                },
              );

              widget.onLeftToggleActive();
            },
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment(1, 0),
              child: Container(
                width: widget.width * 0.5,
                color: Colors.transparent,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  widget.rightDescription,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: _rightDescriptionColor,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stackovfl_70777885/toggle_button.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: ToggleButton(
          width: 300.0,
          height: 60.0,
          toggleBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          toggleBorderColor: (Colors.grey[350])!,
          toggleColor: (Colors.indigo[900])!,
          activeTextColor: Colors.white,
          inactiveTextColor: Colors.grey,
          leftDescription: 'FAVORITES',
          rightDescription: 'HISTORY',
          onLeftToggleActive: () {
            print('left toggle activated');
          },
          onRightToggleActive: () {
            print('right toggle activated');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This should result in the following:

[image: toggle sample]

The `onLeftToggleActive(): () {}` and `onRightToggleActive() {}` in main are triggered depending on where the slider moves.

Comment: This works very well, thank you. I wanted to ask why you use a stateful widget. Is it because we have to toggle the button and change the color? I'm guessing this can not be achieved in a stateless widget. Also why did you use the initState function for the color? I am new to flutter so I just want to understand the logic behind your code.

Comment: Correct, it's stateful because we maintain state for the widget's internal properties. I placed some of the variable assignments in initState because we need the widget to be built first by the parent before we can access some of it’s properties provided in the constructor. There might be other ways to do this as well.

Answer (score 1):

There already is a Widget in Flutter for that: the [ToggleButtons](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html) widget.